# Why do the standardized beta values and CIs of a glm poisson regression model not differ from the unstandardized ones (using report function)?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, standardization

For a specific research question i fitted a generalized linear mixed model using a poisson link function due to the characteristics of my data.

For reporting purposes i used the report package and the report function. However, i noticed that the standardized coefficients and CIs are equal to the normal coefficients and CIs.

Can someone explain why?

I also fitted a glm with poisson to a randomly generated dataset and found the same after running the report(model) function.

Here is a minimal example:

```
# install.packages("report")

library(report)

set.seed(123)
anzahl_unfaelle <- rpois(100, lambda = 3)  # Lambda ist der erwartete Wert
mean(anzahl_unfaelle)
var(anzahl_unfaelle)

wetter <- factor(sample(c("regnerisch", "bewölkt", "sonnig"), 100, replace = TRUE))

daten <- data.frame(anzahl_unfaelle, wetter)

modell <- glm(anzahl_unfaelle ~ wetter, data = daten, family = "poisson")

summary(modell)
report(modell)
```

The output:

The effect of wetter [regnerisch] is statistically non-significant and positive (beta = 4.45e-03, 95% CI [-0.29, 0.29], p = 0.976; Std. beta = 4.45e-03, 95% CI [-0.29, 0.29])

➞ beta = std. beta
➞ CI = std. CI

I appreciate any help!

Lukas

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are asking, in part because your example does not perform two calculations and compare them.  Could you show us explicitly what you are comparing and where you see something (a difference or an equality) that you want to understand better?

Comment: Perhaps the report() function refuses to standardise 0/1 predictors? If it does refuse I would agree with its decision.

Comment: @mdewey is correct, `report` does not standardize categorical variables and therefore the two models being fit are the same. For reference, I had to look that up in the source code, and the call stack is something like `report::report` -> `effectsize::effectsize` -> `parameters::standardize_parameters` -> `datawizard::standardize`. If you're using code to generate your interpretations for you I'd hope you understand very well what it does...